# How to apply .table-striped attribute to pander table in rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, pander

I would like to figure out how to apply the striped attribute to my pander tables in rmarkdown.

I can't really find it at the online help of the Pander library, and *panderOptions* doesn't list it either (or I can't find it), neither can I find it at pandoc.table

Hence the question, how can I use Bootstrap table classes on the following code?

````
```{r}
pander(mtcars)
```
````

Comment: You can tweak the general CSS of the resulting HTML -- other than that, I don't know if it's possible to set a CSS class for a specific table based on the related [markdown specs](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#tables).

Comment: Sounds like as if there is no possibility to change style in an attributive way, as it is possible to add a caption:

    ```pander(mtcars, style = 'grid', caption = "Wide table to be split!")```